# Creating one order update page for different jQuery Sortable pages

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I've managed to get jQuery Sortable to update a database table, which is brilliant.

However it means I now have multiple pages running pretty much the same code other than a change in Table name. So in the example below I have an ajax_lists_order.php, an ajax_staff_order.php, etc with the same code other than **UPDATE table_pages** section in the below which is changed to **UPDATE table_lists**, **UPDATE table_staff**, etc.

So I wondered if there was a way to define the **table_name** in the editing page, so I can just have one ajax_order.php page which has the **table_name** posted into the script, as it does with the $key and $value parts at the moment?

I presume I need to add something to the script in the header, and then an extra bit after parse_str in the ajax_order.php page?

*An example of what I am using at the moment...*

In the Header of a CMS page that edits the order:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#menu-pages').sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            update: function(event, ui) {
            $.post('ajax_pages_order.php', { type: 'orderPages', pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') } );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the Body of the same page:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, page_name, sort_order FROM table_pages ORDER BY sort_order ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
printf('<li id="page_%s">%s</li>', $row['id'], '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['page_name'] . '</a>');
}
```

In ajax_pages_order.php

```
parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);
foreach ($pageOrder['page'] as $key => $value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE table_pages SET `sort_order` = '$key' WHERE `id` = '$value'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I'm terrible when it comes to Javascript and haven't used parse_str before, but I tried adding
**, table: 'table_pages'** after the closing bracket of **'serialize'** in the Header script, and then **parse_str($_POST['table'], $tableName);** in the ordering page above the **parse_str($_POST['pages']** part, but to no avail.